# Programmatically position a button in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-widget, android-button

This is the layout XML I am using.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/tabTransparent"
    android:id="@+id/aLayoutRelative">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout7"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_accounts_aHistoryNotes" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to add the button programmatically in java source. This is what I tried.

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.aLayoutRelative);
LinearLayout lastLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout8);
lastLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, lastLinearLayout.getId());
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastLinearLayout.getId());
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 14, 0, 0);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

Button button9 = new Button(this);
Log.i("tab0", recordTabs.get(0));
button9.setText(""+recordTabs.get(0));
button9.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.addView(button9);
relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);
```

But in the view, the button is vertical with no text on it; aligned towards left of the page (in effect towards relative layout). XML version works well. I reckon the orientation settings turn out to be the culprit. Having googled in various documentations hardly helped.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't this line `layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, lastLinearLayout.getId());` make your view offscreen?

Comment: without that line of code, I can now see the button. Those xml was auto-generated using component design in eclipse. Having seen the button, I would like to set the style of button to small. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve?

for start, remove the

```
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, lastLinearLayout.getId());
```

so you can at least see the button below.

Why to you place the buttons in linear layouts?

Comment: to set the button to fit the size of text (smaller than whole screen width) use LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT instead of LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT:

Comment: well, that is the design spec. What I meant by small button is that it must set the style as android.R.attr.buttonStyleSmall. I got the answer now. I could use button object constructor for the same.

Comment: I have another question for you. How do you make the layout look the same in devices with different screen densities? I read there are a few points to take care of such as use WRAP_CONTENT instead of FILL_PARENT and use dp instead of px. However, even then, I see some alignment leaks in smaller screen devices. Any thoughts?